# XGboost python package gives feature names as none

Tags: python, pickle, xgboost

I am using pickle to load xgboost model.

```
xgb_model = pickle.load(open(path))
cols_when_model_builds = xgb_model.feature_names
```

I use the command `xgb_model.feature_names` to load the feature names. However this gives out an error

```
KeyError: None
```

This was working perfectly fine, however suddenly started throwing this error.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, in my case, the versions of xgboost libraries are different in the trained and the loaded environment. E.g., trained on 1.5.2 and loaded on 1.3.1 gives the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
cols_when_model_builds = xgb_model.get_booster().feature_names
```